# Can a non-parent file for OCI or Indian visa for non-Indian child?

Tags: visas, india, minors

What are the laws for filing OCI for an child? Is a non-parent such as uncle/grandparent allowed to file OCI for a child? or apply for an Indian visa?

Comment: Is the "non-parent" the child's legal guardian?

Comment: @jpatokal yes, legal guardian

Comment: I'm not familiar with India's legislation here, but in general a legal guardian can do everything that a parent can.